# Finding fixed planes of linear transformations

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

So I'm trying to figure out given a linear transformation $T$ how to find a plane that $T$ maps onto itself. One way to state this problem is solving for vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $T(uv)=(uv)\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is two by two and $(uv)$ is the $n\times2$ matrix whose columns are $u$ and $v$. This is clearly an analogue to eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so I tried to come up with a polynomial that will give me $\lambda$ so we can then solve for $u$ and $v$, as we do with eigenvectors. Of course, we will get a different $\lambda$ if we choose a different basis of the same plane, so really we want to solve for $\lambda$ up to similarity.

What I came up with is $$T(uv)=(uv)\lambda\implies \det|T^2-tr(\lambda)T+\det(\lambda)I|=0$$ where $tr(\lambda)$ is the trace. This is a single polynomial in 4 variables, which is a little concerning. I wonder whether some additional clever algebra could give another equation. Alternatively, maybe this one constraint is enough to give $\lambda$ up to similarity.

At this point I tried to find an answer online. What I found is that there is a theory of generalized eigenspaces, but they take a totally different approach. I found a couple textbooks that talk about this, but their approach is completely different. Can anyone explain how the approach I took here fits into the bigger picture?

Edit: I want to point out that typically a fixed plane is not spanned by eigenvectors. For example, $T$ might rotate a plane. In that case no single vector is fixed, but the entire plane is.

Comment: For a real rotation matrix, the planes of rotation are spanned by pairs of _complex_ eigenvectors.

Comment: Are you looking only for two-dimensional subspaces or for _any_ invariant planes? What is the underlying field of your vector space?

Comment: You need more conditions, such as linear independence of $u$ and $v$ and of $Tu$ and $Tv$.

Answer (score 1):

Take two Eigenvectors of $T$. Their linear combinations define a plane. If you apply $T$, you still get a linear combination of these vectors, hence the same plane.

$$T(\alpha\vec u+\beta\vec v)=\lambda\alpha\vec u+\mu\beta\vec v.$$

Comment: Typically a fixed plane will have no eigenvectors, i.e. the plane is rotated. The plane is mapped back onto itself, but no single vector is.

Comment: @A.Kriegman: the question is not asking for fixed vectors. The in-plane transformation is not necessarily a rotation.

Comment: I meant e.g. The point of the rotation example is that it's a fixed plane with no eigenvectors. Your answer works for diagonalizable matrices, but take for example the two by two matrix $T=((11)(01))$. This has eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 2, but only one eigenvector..

Comment: @A.Kriegman: if you know the answer, why did you ask the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your linear transformation is represented by a matrix $A$ such that $T(V) = AV$

If $U$ and $V$ are two linearly independent eighenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda _1$  and $\lambda _2$ respectively, then $$T(\alpha U + \beta V) = A( \alpha U + \beta V) = \alpha AU + \beta AV = (\alpha \lambda_1)U + ( \beta \lambda_2)V$$

That is the plane spanned by $U$ and $V$ maps to itself under the linear transformation.

Comment: Typically a fixed plane will have no eigenvectors, i.e. the plane is rotated. The plane is mapped back onto itself, but no single vector is.

Comment: @A.Kriegman As I mentioned in a comment to your question, fixed planes of a real rotation matrix are spanned by pairs of _complex_ eigenvalues. By taking real and imaginary parts, you can get a real basis for the plane.

Comment: You are right, but there are other transformations for which the span of eigenvectors is degenerate. Take for example $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. In general you need a different approach for any non-diagonalizable matrix.